# What is the process for upgrading governance from v1 to v2?

Tags: governance

1. Which old pallets will be removed from the runtime?
2. What migration will be carried out?
3. Which new pallets need to be added to the runtime?
4. What other important things do we need? A fellowship group?

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question to have documented here:

1. Which old pallets will be removed from the runtime?

```
phragmen_election
democracy
council
technical_committee
technical_membership
pallet_tips
```

2. What migration will be carried out?

You might want to clean all the storage from v1, so first you have to carry some miragtions to unlock/reserve balances, see the example in [Kusama](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/polkadot/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L1739):

```rs
// Unlock/unreserve balances from Gov v1 pallets that hold them
// https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/6749
pallet_elections_phragmen::migrations::unlock_and_unreserve_all_funds::UnlockAndUnreserveAllFunds<UnlockConfig>,
pallet_democracy::migrations::unlock_and_unreserve_all_funds::UnlockAndUnreserveAllFunds<UnlockConfig>,
pallet_tips::migrations::unreserve_deposits::UnreserveDeposits<UnlockConfig, ()>,

// Delete storage key/values from all Gov v1 pallets
frame_support::migrations::RemovePallet<DemocracyPalletName, <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight>,
frame_support::migrations::RemovePallet<CouncilPalletName, <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight>,
frame_support::migrations::RemovePallet<TechnicalCommitteePalletName, <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight>,
frame_support::migrations::RemovePallet<PhragmenElectionPalletName, <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight>,
frame_support::migrations::RemovePallet<TechnicalMembershipPalletName, <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight>,
frame_support::migrations::RemovePallet<TipsPalletName, <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight>
```

Follow this PRs for more details:

- [[FRAME] Remove Gov V1 from Polkadot and Kusama & unlock/unreserve funds](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/485)
- [migration: unlock/unreserve Gov v1 balances, remove Gov V1 pallets from polkadot runtime, and remove Gov V1 pallet key/values from storage](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/7314)

3. Which new pallets need to be added to the runtime?

```
pallet_conviction_voting
pallet_referenda
pallet_whitelist
```

For the fellowship:

```
pallet_ranked_collective
```

And the custom origins for governance interventions.

```
pallet_custom_origins
```

4. What other important things do we need?

The PR that removes OpenGov1 in Kusama and introduce it into Polakdot: [Introduce OpenGov into Polkadot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1177).

Other PRs might be useful: [Logic for the (Core) Fellowship](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13503).

This process has been implemented a few weeks ago in Westend and Rococo too:
[OpenGov in Westend and Rococo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1177)